# Visual Studio - Error: Unable to download installation files

Tags: django, visual-studio, installation, mod-wsgi

I'm following a nice tutorial on hosting Django on Apache, for that I need to install mod_wsgi using pip. This needs c++ 14.0 or higher .. I've been trying to install visual studio community edition and it's tools using the microsoft installer. However, a bugging error keeps chacing me:

"Unable to download installation files. Check your internet connection and try again"

Now my internet connection is fine, I also did many attempts to restart, and re-download - cmd commands for offline installation and many many attempts.

I need help here as It is driving me crazy!:D can anybody please help?

all the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visual Studio - Error: Unable to download installation files

You can try these steps:

**First**, make sure that you use administrator account to log on to the PC and your Internet can access any websites.

**1)** delete the Installer folder under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\`

**2)** Right-click on the `vs_xxxxx_xxxx.exe`(installer program)-->`Properties`-->`Digital Signatures`-->you can see "signature list"-->Select signature and then Click on `Details` button-->Click on `View certificate` button--> Click on `Install certificate` and follows installation wizard.

**3)** Fire up **Run**, type `gpedit.msc`

- Brows to the following location: `Computer Configuration`-->`Administrative Templates`-->`System`-->`Internet Communication Management`-->`Internet Communication settings` then find the entry `Turn off Automatic Root Certificates Update` and open her up and set it to `Disabled`.

**4)** Get Windows to check for updates and if so, update it.

**5)** Then run the installer as administrator to install it.

**In addition**, if you create an offline installation, please use like this:(remember to add `--lang en-us`)

`vs_community.exe --layout C:\vs2019offline --lang en-us`

**Besides**, when you finish it, please install the three certificates as administrator which are in the certificates folder of the offline package and after that, install the installer.

**Also**, make sure that these certificates are in the trusted folder.

Comment: thanks alot .. it works.. windows updates saved me.. moreover, it seems that mod_wsgi really needs special compillers and there tools to be correctly installed. i'm still new to this server issues .. thanks again

Comment: The certificate i see expired in 2021. Where do i find the new one?